# Rails: Email a pdf generated with prawn to an email sent by ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, prawn, email-attachments

I have an ecommerce app.  I'm using Prawn to generate pdf invoices of orders.  I'm using a standard Prawn setup.  In views/admin/orders, I have a file called show.pdf.prawn.  When the seller is viewing an order in his admin section, he clicks a link that opens the pdf version of the orders/show view.  This all works perfectly.

Now, the tricky part.  When an order is completed, I send an email to the seller.  What I'd like to do is attach the pdf invoice version of orders/show to that email.  Is it possible to do this?  The documentation on email attachments is pretty limited and I haven't been able to find resources that go through the workflow that I'm describing.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sending an attachment with an email is fairly easy with ActionMailer:

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def email_with_attachment(pdf_invoice)
    .
    .
    .

    attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
      a.filename = "some_invoice.pdf"
      a.body = pdf_invoice
    end
  end

end
```

One problem you might have with this is generating the pdf file outside of the prawnto method (when using the prawnto plugin)-
If this is is the case I strongly recommend you to use [this approach](http://wiki.github.com/sandal/prawn/using-prawn-in-rails) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i managed to do it by generating the pdf from a model, much easier than evaluating the template. I replied with the answer here :

[Save a Prawn PDF as a Paperclip attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034871/save-a-prawn-pdf-as-a-paperclip-attachment/20334360#20334360)